# Android Widget Update TextView Text

Tags: android, android-widget

I have an android widget which is updated 1 time per day (as stated in the providerinfo.xml file). 
Here is, currently, my onUpdate method:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) 
{
        RemoteViews rvs = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
        rvs.setTextViewText(R.id.textviewquote, "we updated! yay!");
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context, main.class), rvs);
}
```

However, my textview NEVER changes.  onUpdate is called at the beginning, when the widget is first created right? So how does one actually change the text in a textview?

Thanks

Edit:
Provider Info:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="294dp"
android:minHeight="72dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
android:initialLayout="@layout/main">
```

And Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".main" >
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
       </intent-filter>
       <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                  android:resource="@xml/appwidgetproviderinfo" />
</receiver>
```

Update:
The Method onUpdate() is not even getting called.  Can someone tell me why?

**Major Update: In android 2.3, the onUpdate() method is NOT called, but in android 2.2, it IS called.  I wonder if this is a bug, or perhaps they changed the way widgets work.**

Comment: Where did You set update frequency? In Manifest or through AlarmManager?

Comment: You can put a log inside onUpdate to make sure that once you add the widget for the first time, it is called.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check my updates:

Major Update: In android 2.3, the onUpdate() method is NOT called, but in android 2.2, it IS called. I wonder if this is a bug, or perhaps they changed the way widgets work.

I'm accepting this as the answer. We'll see if google does anything about it.